# What is a good pattern for preloading asynchronous data?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I am building some functionality in Zendesk using mostly vanilla JS (jQuery is available too) and I have a button that needs to run an API call to get some data first before it can do its "real" job.  But the async data is static - it will never change per user or session - so I was thinking to preload it as soon as the page loads, to save some time later.  But the button should not assume the data has been loaded, even if it probably will be 90% of the time.  I don't want to set up any annoying race conditions.

In the past, in similar scenarios, I have handled this by disabling the button by default and enabling it once the async data has loaded.  But I was just wondering if there was a better pattern.

Comment: Better in what way? Using the end of the async operation seems accurate way of handling the situation, I'm not sure what you want to improve here.

Comment: TBH @VLAZ, I wasn't sure myself, but Quentin nailed it.  With his solution, there's no need for any clunky mechanism for storing the cached data or signifying that the button is ready by disabling and enabling it.  I can simply treat the cached data as though it were available and the simple addition of `await` ensures that it will be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you load data asynchronously with a modern API (like `fetch`) then you will be using Promises to manage the asynchronicity.

Store the promise in your cache when you start to load it.

Then, when you want to use it (e.g. by clicking on the button) you can just `await` the stored Promise. If the precaching has finished it will already be in a resolved state. If it is still pending then the operation will pause as normal until the data is available.

---

If you're using an older API (like `XMLHttpRequest`) then you can wrap the operation in a Promise manually.

---

```js
const fetchData = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    console.log("Simulating a long running data fetching operation");
    let percent_done = 0;

    (function fetchChunk() {
      percent_done += 10;
      console.log(`Loaded ${percent_done}%`);
      if (percent_done >= 100) resolve("Here is your data");
      else setTimeout(fetchChunk, 1000);
    })();
  });
};

const cache = fetchData();

const logData = async() => {
  const clickTime = new Date();
  const data = await cache;
  const now = new Date();
  console.log(`Data was "${data}" from click at ${clickTime.toLocaleTimeString()} (time now is ${now.toLocaleTimeString()})`);
};

document.querySelector("button").addEventListener('click', logData);
```

```html
<button>Click me</button>
```

Comment: That's really nice, thanks for that!